# octave fft of sinus function

Tags: function, matlab, octave, trigonometry

I need to use FFT function on sinus.

this is my sinus function:

```
octave:1> t=(0:1/16000:1);
octave:2> A=2;
octave:3> x=A*sin(2*pi*80*t);
```

this is how I try to make fft:

```
octave:60> l=length(x);
octave:61> k=fft(x,l);
```

It makes me triangle lol.. how can I do this properly?

@edit
screen, is it good looking fft of sin? can I improve it somehow?
[image]

@edit2
Can I improve it, so it would look better?

Comment: makes you triangle? huh?  if you plot it, you may get a funky looking output because k is a complex array.  try plot(abs(k)) for amplitude.

Comment: thx, can you check if this is how fft of sin should look? I am adding a screenshot.

Comment: why would you use FFT on a sinus, seeing as a sinus has no sidebands, no frequencies other that it's own. sinus is a pure frequency, it could never justify being scanned, except for learning and research purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything looks good from the screen shot.

1. The magnitude of the FFT of a sine function is two spike like objects. What you are showing is correct.
2. The FFT is an algorithm that produces a result similar to the continuous Fourier transform, but is different in a few ways. Besides being discrete, Matlab's FFT warps the values. This can be undone with `fftshift(k)`.